# C - Insertion sort using linked list with unordered array

Tags: c, linked-list, insertion-sort, unordered

```
void insert(struct EMP* emp[])
{
    struct EMP* previous = NULL;
    struct EMP* current = top;

    int i;
    int j;

    previous = current;
    current = current -> next;

    for(i = 1; i < numEmps; i++)
    {
        j = i;
        while(j > 0 && previous -> id > current -> id)
        {
            previous = current;
            j--;
        }

        current = current -> next;
    }
}
```

So, the parameter is an unordered array, and I want to order it using an insertion sort. The thing I am having problems with is it needs to be linked lists. Any suggestions? Above is my existing insertion sort function that doesnt work.

Comment: Of course it doesn't work, you use `previous` while it's still `NULL`.

Comment: I think previous=current=top so no problem there.

Comment: I added where previous equals current, then current equals the next one.... It builds and runs, but nothing changes to the sort. Any ideas?

Comment: Is insertion-sort mandated, because if I *had* to code the sort I'd [heap-sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort) the original vector. Of course, if there are no algorithm requirements, you could always use `std::sort` on the original container and call it good. On the other hand, if you want to sort the *same* linked list, it is one data structure that merge-sorts in constant space because of the ability to arbitrarily refer node pointers to new targets.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to look more carefully at the insertion sort algorithm. In essence it requires a new target list that add elements to (specifically you insert the elements in the correct place as you build this second list). So at the heart of your misunderstanding is the idea that this can be done 'in-place' on a single list.

It would be saner and easier to implement this second list as a linked list because you need to be able to efficiently insert elements into the list at an arbitrary point.